# all pairs shortest path

Tags: c++, graph-theory

I am surprised why the following code that calculates all pairs shortest  pairs does not show me any output.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int Min(int a,int b){
    return a<=b? a:b;
}

int cost[10][10],a[10][10],i,j,k,c;

int main(){

    int n,m;
    cout<<"enter number of vertices "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"enter number of edges "<<endl;
    cin>>m;
    for (k=1;k<=m;k++)
    {
        cin>>i>>j>>c;
        a[i][j]=cost[i][j]=c;
    }

    for ( i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for ( j=1;j<m;j++){
            if (a[i][j]==0 && i!=j)
                a[i][j]=40000;
        }
    }

    for (k=1;k<=n;k++)
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
            for( j=1;j<=n;j++)
                a[i][j]=min(a[i][j],a[i][k]+a[k][j]);

    cout<<" resultant adj matrix \n";
    for (i=1;j<=n;j++){
        for (j=1;i<=n;i++){
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some typos:
The last loops should look like this:

```
 for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
     for (j=1;j<=n;j++){
```

Comment: can you specify what is not working? The printing of the output?

Comment: with these changes it prints: enter number of vertices 
2
enter number of edges 
2
3
4
5
6
4
3
 resultant adj matrix 
0 0 
40000 0

Comment: It prints something like that: resultant adj matrix 
0 40000 40000 
40000 0 40000 
40000 40000 0

Comment: 1 2 4
2 1 6
1 3 11
3 1 3
2 3 2

Comment: with this array  (two dimensional) nothing

Comment: In the for loops at the end, I think you might have mixed up `i` and `j`. Edit: Oh, that was what tune2fs meant, sorry

Comment: How can we help you, for me it will print out the resulting adj matrix (with the changes above). Therefore you should control your code if is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just fix the typos in your loops, especially here:

```
cout<<" resultant adj matrix \n";
for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
  for (j=1;j<=m;j++){
    cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
  }
cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class Main{
    static int min(int a,int b)
    {
      if(a<b)
        return a;
      else
        return b;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      int n,i,j,k;
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the number of nodes :- ");
      n=sc.nextInt();
      int t=n;
      int mat[][]=new int[n+1][n+1];
      System.out.println("Consider 5000 as infinity :- ");
      System.out.println("Enter the values of adjacency matrix :- ");
      for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
      {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
          mat[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
        }
      }
      System.out.println("MAT0"+" = ");
      for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
      {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
          System.out.print(mat[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
      }
      for(k=1;k<=n;k++)
      {
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
          for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
          {
            mat[i][j]=min(mat[i][j],mat[i][k]+mat[k][j]);
          }
        }
        System.out.println("MAT"+k+" = ");
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
          for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
          {
            System.out.print(mat[i][j]+" ");
          }
          System.out.print("\n");
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: The question is about C++, this answer is not.